# Realm nested collection updating listview in transaction

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, realm

I'm having some issues with UI updating within a BeginWrite transaction in Realm .NET / Xamarin.Forms

I have 2 models, ModelA and ModelB. ModelA contains an IList { get; } of ModelB.

I have 2 listview pages, the first populated with bound ModelA. Navigating through an entry takes you to the 2nd page with a listview bound to the ModelBs that ModelA contains and a button to add new ModelBs to ModelA.

If I do this within a Write transaction it will all work as intended. When you add a ModelB to ModelA you can see this in the ModelB list immediately and everything is persisted.

What I want is to do this within a BeginWrite and only commit when a save button is pressed. This works, but the ModelB list UI won't update. Only when navigating back into the page do the ModelB list entries appear.

Can this work the way I want?

Attached is my code from the 2nd page (listview of ModelA.ModelB) viewmodel (FreshMVVM being used).

```
public class SecondPageModel : FreshMvvm.FreshBasePageModel
{
    Transaction _transaction;

    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }

    public SecondPageModel() { }

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        base.Init(initData);
        ModelA = initData as ModelA;

        var db = Realm.GetInstance();
        _transaction = db.BeginWrite();
    }

    public Command NewModelB
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                var newB = new ModelB();
                newB.Name = "B";
                ModelA.ModelBs.Add(newB);
            });
        }
    }

    public Command SaveModelA
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                _transaction.Commit();
                await CoreMethods.PopPageModel();
            });
        }
    }

    protected override void ViewIsDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.ViewIsDisappearing(sender, e);
        _transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The collection change notifications are emitted from the database itself. So until something is saved to the database, nothing has changed (thus you only get the notifications after the commit). One way to work around it is to instead create the object and save it eagerly, but mark it as in-progress. Then on save, remove the flag and on disappearing, delete all incomplete objects:

```
public Command NewModelB
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            db.Write(() =>
            {
                ModelA.ModelBs.Add(new ModelB
                {
                    Name = "B",
                    InProgress = true
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

public Command SaveModelA
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            db.Write(() =>
            {
                var toCommit = ModelA.ModelBs.Where(m => m.InProgress);
                foreach (var modelB in toCommit)
                {
                    modelB.InProgress = false;
                }
            });

            await CoreMethods.PopPageModel();
        });
    }
}

protected override void ViewIsDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsDisappearing(sender, e);

    db.Write(() =>
    {
        var toDelete = ModelA.ModelBs.Where(m => m.InProgress).ToArray();
        foreach (var modelB in toDelete)
        {
            db.Remove(modelB);
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously, this may leave some dangling objects if the app crashes or if the user quits it before navigating away, so you'll probably want to add some cleanup logic in your application startup.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately this doesn't cover the whole scope of my problems. I also have other ModelA properties that need to be set (and saved or discarded) in the same page, which before were covered by the BeginWrite transaction and binding. As I can't have Writes within a BeginWrite I can't think of how to meet my needs.